# Is this proof of the euclidian algorithm correct?

Tags: proof-verification, algorithms

I have come up with my own proof of euclidian algorithm and I am not sure if it is correct and I need help (definitely) formalizing it better.

```
ggT(a,b):
  if a > b: return ggt(a, b - a);
  if b > a: return ggt(b,a - b);
  if a = b: return a;
```

with $M := \{ p |a \, \land \, p|b \}$ and $ggT(a,b):= k \in M |\, \forall p \in M  : p \leq k$

**Proof**:

(0) There is a greatest possible divider

Every natural number can be divided by one.

(1) $ggT(a,b) = ggT(b,a)$

Proof:

Since ggT(a,b) is only defined as the greatest number in the set $M$ and $M$ does not change itself through swaping a,b, $ggT(a,b) = ggT(b,a)$ must be true.

(2) $a > b \implies ggT(a,b) = ggT(a-b,b)$

Proof:

Let $k$ be the greatest possible divider:

$k|b \land k|a \implies n\times k = b \land n'\times k = a \implies
(a-b)/k = n + n'$, thus $(a-b)$ can be divided by k. But there cannot be a greater divisor, since this divisor could be able to divide a and b and could by definition not exist.

(3): $b > a \implies ggT(a,b) = ggT(a,b-a)$

$ggT(a,b) =^{(I)} ggt(b,a) =^{(II)} ggT(b-a,a) =^{(I)} ggT(a,b-a) $

(4) ggT(a>0,b>0) halts in every case:

If a > b: Then a gets smaller but can not get smaller than 1.
If b > a: Then b gets smaller but can not get smaller than 1.
If a = b: Function returns.

Thus, for every a,b the function will halt definetly after max(a,b)steps.

(5) ggT(a,a) = a

Every number divides itself. There is no bigger number which can divide the number but itself.

(Conclusion) Since the function will halt and the final return must be equally the same as initial greatest divisor, the algorithm must be correct.

PLEASE HELP, IT TOOK ME WAY TO LONG TO FORMULATE THIS SO BADLY!

Thank you!

Comment: This seems correct to me; Just as a remark, you are working on a quite formal level already

Comment: But the level of abstraction is not high, is it. Thank you!